# Python - How to use regex to find a text?

Tags: python, regex

Please bear with me, I'm new in Python. I have a text, and I want to get the value after `^s` until the next `^` so for example there's `^s100^` then the value is `100`. This is what I've tried so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re

text="^request^ #13#10#13#10^s100^GET http://facebook.com #13#10Host: http://facebook.com #13#10X-Online-Host: http://facebook.com #13#10X-Forward-Host: http://facebook.com #13#10Connection: Keep-Alive#13#10#13#10"
if re.split(r'\^s',text):
    print "found it"
```

The problem is that it always returns `found it` even if I change the regex to `re.split(r'\^bla',text)` and basically any text, it will always return `found it` Please help me to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need as much code, try the following:

```
import re
text = "^request^ #13#10#13#10^s100^GET http://facebook.com #13#10Host: http://facebook.com #13#10X-Online-Host: http://facebook.com #13#10X-Forward-Host: http://facebook.com #13#10Connection: Keep-Alive#13#10#13#10"
match = re.search(r"\^s(\d+)\^", text)
if match:
    print match.group(1)
```

---

**Regex Explanation:**

```
\^s(\d+)\^

Match the character “^” literally «\^»
Match the character “s” literally (case sensitive) «s»
Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(\d+)»
   Match a single character that is a “digit” (ASCII 0–9 only) «\d+»
      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
Match the character “^” literally «\^»
```

---

[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/PIazP7)

Comment: I just "love" it when other members come after me, copy my answer and their answer gets accepted. Only that I'm usually not expecting it to happen by veteran users like yourself. Very disappointing...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paranoia -> "**Paranoid thinking typically includes persecutory...**"

Comment: It's a fact that you posted your answer a few minutes after I posted mine. And it's also a fact that it's the same answer. Where does paranoia come to the equation ?

Comment: I can only tell you that I didn't copy your answer. Is that enough for you?

Comment: Nope. When I want to post an answer, and I see that someone else already posted what I thought about, I do not go ahead and post a "duplicate answer". But it seems that my logic doesn't apply to all people...

Comment: The answer isn't duplicated (my regex is different). You're just annoyed because the OP marked my answer as correct. I've spent way too much time with this, roger out...

Comment: True I am indeed annoyed and you can probably imagine why, putting yourself in my shoes... As long as you feel good with yourself - I wish you all the best.

Comment: A  bit sleepy already, but I do feel good and I hope you too, because you're answer is also correct, 1+

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want is [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html):

```
import re

text="^request^ #13#10#13#10^s100^GET http://facebook.com #13#10Host: http://facebook.com #13#10X-Online-Host: http://facebook.com #13#10X-Forward-Host: http://facebook.com #13#10Connection: Keep-Alive#13#10#13#10"
m = re.search(r'\^s(.*)\^',text)
print m.group(1)  # 100
```

Comment: what does `group` mean ?

Comment: @hillz when you're doing a regex and in it you put brackets `...(...)...` whatever matches the term inside the brackets is considered as a "matched group". There could be multiple matches, but in your case you want the first one, which is why we call `m.group(1)`